# probability of poisson disto

Tags: probability

35yr male returning to school for undergraduate. Preparing for entrance exam to test out of some math classes. Working probability and statistics problems obtained from teachers aid. Been over 15yrs and I am a bit rusty. HELP APPRECIATED!

A limousine service has 3 cars which are leased to customers for a day. The number of
cars ordered on any day is a Poisson random variable N, with E[N] = 2. Then
C = min(N,3), where C is the random variable representing the number of cars leased on
any day.

(a) Find P(N > C), the probability that 1 or more car orders go unfulfilled on any day.

Thus far I have: P(N>3) = 1-P(N<3) = P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3)   Using the equation for PMF of Poisson Random Variable  I conclude that probability is 1-.8566=.1433  thus it is 14%

(b) (Find E[C]

Here I am not sure if my logic is correct but I see this as simply   E[C] = lamda
and from the above E[N] =2   therefore E[C] = 2

Can anyone confirm I am on the right page....  Or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

On the first question, I get roughly $0.142876539$. It seems likely that you did the question correctly, but perhaps rounded and rekeyed during the numerical calculation.  It is best to learn to use any memory feature your calculator has.

Here is how to find the expectation of $C$. The random variable $C$ takes on values $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$. So
$$E(C)=(0)\Pr(C=0)+(1)\Pr(C=1)+(2)\Pr(C=2)+(3)\Pr(C=3).\tag{1}$$

The probabilities for $0,1,2,$ are the Poisson distribution probabilities.

The probability that $C=3$ is $1-\left(\Pr(C=0)+\Pr(C=1)+\Pr(C=2)\right)$. For if the demand on any particular day is $\gt 3$, then the number $C$ of cars rented that day is $3$.

For the calculation, it may be best to simplify the expression (1) algebraically before using the calculator. I get $3-9e^{-2}$.